# Does std::terminate() trigger stack unwinding?

Tags: c++, raii

I've been trying to implement `Exception` class, and for program termination i've decided to use `std::terminate()`, but i'm not suse whether or not `std::terminate()` triggers stack unwinding process.

For example, if i compile and run this code:

```cpp
struct Test {
    Test() {
        std::cout << "Constructed\n";
    }
    ~Test() {
        std::cout << "Destructed\n";
    }
};

int main() {
    Test t;
    std::terminate();
    return 0;
}
```

it will output this:

```
Constructed
terminate called without an active exception
```

and it seems that destructor is not being called.

Comment: Why does the exception class need to end program execution (via `std::termiante` or other)?

Comment: @user17732522, I thought that is what uncaught exceptions do

Comment: yes uncaught exceptions do that, but there shouldnt be any uncaught exception, otherwise its a bug imho. If you want to shutdown in a clean way you should call [`std::exit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/exit), instead of terminate

Comment: Yes that's true, but completely different from explicitly calling `std::terminate`. The given answer doesn't apply to implicit calls to `std::terminate` as a result of an uncaught exception. (The exception class doesn't/shouldn't call `std::terminate` itself.)

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number But `std::exit` won't call automatic storage duration destructors either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The standard handler for `std::terminate()` calls directly `std::abort`.

If you take a look [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/abort), you will find out that `std::abort()` did not call any of the destructors.

> Destructors of variables with automatic, thread local (since C++11) and static storage durations are not called. Functions registered with std::atexit() and std::at_quick_exit (since C++11) are also not called. Whether open resources such as files are closed is implementation defined. An implementation defined status is returned to the host environment that indicates unsuccessful execution.

Comment: Be mindful that at least MSVCs implementation up to and including v141 *did* in fact try to call destructors for variables with static storage duration regardless. `abort()` was implemented incorrectly with regard to that.